# Why some options are missing in new product

Tags: magento-1, catalog, products

I am using **Magento 1.7** and problem is this I have already some product in **Magento admin** when I edit any product then I find all options in inventory section but when I create new product then I couldn't find some options please see attached screenshots

[image: Missing some options]

This is following screenshot of product edit

[image: Found complete options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because when you add product of screenshot then you have enabled managed stock from `admin -> system -> configuration -> inventory -> product stock options ->  manage stock` set to YES but when you try to add new product then according to screenshot1 then this option is set to no please enable manage stock from admin for reenable all options

Answer (score 1):

The difference between screenshot 1 and 2 is that in screenshot 1 the 'Manage stock' option is set to *no* following your global config.

If you set it to *yes* for that product by unselecting 'use config settings' or change the global default in the *system > configuration > catalog > stock > settings productstock > manage stock* you well get all the options in screenshot 2